# Export queries from SSMS to files - not the results but the query

Tags: sql-server, export, ssms

I want to export all my queries as individual files for purposes of putting them *into* mercurial source control, but I don't know how to export the individual queries as individual files without having to open each one, then save to the folder, then add into the project, or some equally convoluted process.

I wouldn't mind having to add each one individually, but how do I get them out of the database as individual files without opening them all and doing each one save as? Ostensibly I would like them named with the name they have in the database right now.

I could easily dump the whole lot into one long file using database tasks, but that's not really super helpful is it?

I have SSMS 2k5 and 2k8 (and VS 2k5, 2k8, 2010 to boot) to work with, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the database. Select Generate Script. On the last page. Script To file you can choose single file or file per object

Comment: OMG, I totally spaced out everytime I saw that screen, never saw "one per object". Perfectly easy. Thanks a zillion. Accepting this one over @gbn on account of earlier posting even tho both answered exactly. Also, out of upvotes so will upvote both later tonight.

Answer (score 2):

When you script a database in SSMS you have the option of one file per objects.

SMO is useful with a small app to iterate through

Third party tools like Red Gate SQL Compare (there are other free tools) can script too

Comment: As for redgate, waiting on some money from the boss for licenses later this month (or so I have been promised ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I would write a small C# program which extracts your database object via SMO and stores them in your filesystem the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather easy to write stored procedures which fetches the definition into the result as text. sp_helptext could be used as start. 
Than you can use PowerShell to write the Output to the file system.

It sounds as if this would fit rather good into the Really Simple Data Dictionary codeplex project. [link text](http://rsdd.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the codeplex I'm gonna have to look into that one.